# un-avoidable libxml2 mem leak due to crash if cleanup attempted

Tags: c++, xpath, memory-leaks, libxml2

We're using libxml2 to resolve xpaths against an xmlcontext which contains "registered" vars. Our destructor attempts to clean up an xmlXPathContextPtr and a xmlDocPtr:

```
~CLibXpathContext()
{
    xmlXPathFreeContext(m_xpathContext); //causes crash if any vars registered
    xmlFreeDoc(m_xmlDoc);
}
```

We're registering vars as follows:

```
virtual bool addVariable(const char * name,  const char * val) override
{
    if (m_xpathContext )
    {
        xmlXPathObjectPtr valx = xmlXPathWrapCString((char*)val);
        return xmlXPathRegisterVariable(m_xpathContext, (xmlChar *)name, valx) == 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The libxml2 cleanup code is as follows:

```
void xmlXPathFreeContext(xmlXPathContextPtr ctxt) {
if (ctxt == NULL) return;

if (ctxt->cache != NULL)
    xmlXPathFreeCache((xmlXPathContextCachePtr) ctxt->cache);
    xmlXPathRegisteredNsCleanup(ctxt);
    xmlXPathRegisteredFuncsCleanup(ctxt);
    xmlXPathRegisteredVariablesCleanup(ctxt); // this is causing the issue
    xmlResetError(&ctxt->lastError);
    xmlFree(ctxt);
}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, or if the libxml2 code has an issue?

We also attempted to unregister all registered vars before calling the xmlXPathFreeContext method...

Comment: Are you sure that those C-style casts are correct? What if `name` is still referenced after `addVariable` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `xmlXPathNewCString(const char *)` instead of `xmlXPathWrapCString(char *)`. The former creates a copy of the string while the latter transfers ownership of the string to the XPath object, freeing the *original string* when the XPath object is destroyed.

Comment: Great catch. The mem. leak is in fact avoidable. Thanks again!